# Confure DTR for UART in Java ME8 on Raspberry Pi board

Tags: java, java-me, serial-port, raspberry-pi, uart

I'm writing a test application for UART in Java ME8 and this applicatuon is running on Raspberry Pie board. I have used GPIO 15 and 15 for TXD and RXD. and made a level converter DB9. DB9 connected tested with Pi to PC(working). But when I connect Pi with other device (Pi - Device) its not working. this is due to DTR required for other device.

On Pi board I don't have option for DTR pin, how can I solve this issue? 
is there anyway we can use jdk.dio.uart.UART to solve this ?

Can I set DTR using jdk.dio.uart.UART? Can I make DB9 pin4 always high to solve this problem?

```
import jdk.dio.DeviceManager;
import jdk.dio.uart.UART;
import jdk.dio.uart.UARTConfig;

 private UART uart;

private InputStream iStream;
private OutputStream oStream;


    private final int UART_DEVICE_ID = 40;    //standard for Rasp Pi
    private final int UART_BAUD_RATE = 9600;
    private final int UART_DATA_BITS = UARTConfig.DATABITS_8;
    private final int UART_PARITY_BIT = UARTConfig.PARITY_NONE;
    private final int UART_STOP_BIT = UARTConfig.STOPBITS_1;

    uart =(UART) DeviceManager.open(UART_DEVICE_ID); // 40 is UART device ID
        uart.setBaudRate(UART_BAUD_RATE);
        uart.setDataBits(UART_DATA_BITS);
        uart.setParity(UART_PARITY_BIT);
        uart.setStopBits(UART_STOP_BIT);



        oStream = Channels.newOutputStream(uart);
        iStream = Channels.newInputStream(uart);
```

Thanks,
Ashok